# remove commas from a string, and also print code for each word before and after the comma

Tags: php, mysql

Hopefully the question title makes sense.

Just wondering if it is possible to get data from a record in mysql, then remove all the commas and then print each item individually?

I have a column called tags, and an example is in one of the records the tags are

`"rock,bass,alternative"`

What I want to do is remove the commas and then print the html code `<a href ="/TAG NAME">` before and `</a>` after each individual tag.

So far my code is :

```
 $id = $_GET['id']; 


 $station = mysql_query ( "SELECT * FROM `Stations` WHERE `ID` = '$id'" );
 $sta   = mysql_fetch_object ( $station );

<? echo "$sta->tags";?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Explode on the `,`, giving you an array, Print each item and concatenate the string encapsulstaion.

```
 $tags = explode(',', $sta->tags);

 foreach($tags as $tag):
     echo "$tag";
 endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, but you should really be keeping your tags in another table.  This would allow you to do things like pull up stations with a given tag, which can only be done very inefficiently with your current schema.

So you would have a table like `Tags` with `ID` and `DESCRIPTION` columns, and any other information you may want about your tags, and another table `StationTags` with `STATION_ID` and `TAG_ID` columns with foreign key constraints to the relevant ID columns, to link the stations to the tags.